# Git merge two git repositories with history

Tags: git

I have two repositories: `project.git` which has been the main repository for our project, then we started another **empty** git repository called `newproject.git` we pulled out pieces and parts of code that can be reused from `project.git` and used in the code base in `newproject.git`.

My question is: **is there a way to merge `newproject.git` back into `project.git` such that, the history/commits are appended together, as if `newproject.git` never exited. BUT all the files in `newproject.git` will replace the contents in `project.git`?**

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a lot of work, given the current state of merge tools!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253594/using-git-to-merge-two-directories-with-common-parent-but-different-sha1 this may be helpful.

Comment: @pktangyue thanks, this is exactly what I needed. If you add your comment as the answer, I would be happy to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Bill you can upvote comments as well, cant you

Answer (score 1):

You can add your newproject.git repository to the project.git as another remote. And you have two remote repositories: origin and newproject.

`git remote add newproject newproject.git`

or set other options (like -m)

`git help remote`

You can pull from origin/newproject

`git pull origin`

or

`git pull newproject`

and you just have to merge to your origin master and push to origin (project.git).

`git push origin master`

Comment: ...and how to merge newproject with project?