# Git merge 2 versions no common ancestor

Tags: git, mercurial, merge

I have my source code in a mercurial repo, whereas the master branch has been moved from mercurial to a git repo. The current git master branch head and my mercurial version has conflicts. The git master was created as a new repo and not derived from the original mercurial repo. How can I merge my modifications with the master branch's modifications?

If I create a new branch from the master, overwrite the sources with my mercurial sources and merge it with the master, git doesn't detect conflict (I suppose because we have no common ancestor version)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253594/using-git-to-merge-two-directories-with-common-parent-but-different-sha1 this may be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't think that it would.  If you create a new branch *from master* then you *do* in fact have a common ancestor, and that common ancestor is in fact, master itself.  This means that the merge result is actually your new branch, since it's a fast-forward from master.

If you were to create a new branch with no history (or no relationship to master) then you would get the merge conflicts you expect.  You can create a new orphan branch:

```
git checkout --orphan new_branch
```

And *then* copy your sources in from mercurial, you will be able to merge with master.  Any files that are not identical between the two branches will be marked as conflicts.

Comment: git checkout doesn't create a new branch does it? Or do you mean I should create a branch and then check it out using --orphan

Comment: `git checkout` will create a new branch when given the `-b` or `--orphan` flags.

Comment: hmm doesn't work to well in my case: "git checkout --orphan tm"
Switched to a new branch 'tm'    "git log"
fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'  "git branch -a
  master"
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master

Comment: That's what you should be seeing.  You just created a branch with no history (ie, no `HEAD`) -- aka an "orphan branch" -- which is exactly what you want if you expect to have no relationship.  Once you add and commit your files, `git log` should show you only a single commit, the one you just made.